# Send Data from Table Cell to database

Tags: database, codeigniter, html-table

I am trying to use a editable table to update the database without using the form. My 
`<td>` tag has contenteditable attribute so the use can edit the table cell. My problem is that I am using Codeigniter and not sure how to send the table cell data to my controller to update the database. Just wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen for a (delayed) keyup event and capture the jQuery.text().  Once you capture the text string send it along to your codeigniter controller with your csrf_token via ajax, viola.

**This should work fine(jQuery), ive not tested mind**

```
$(function(){

        var tbl = $("table"),
            tblTd = tbl.find("td"),
            timeout = '';

        tblTd.bind('keyup', function(){

                var td = $(this);

                if(timeout) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = null;
                }

                timeout = setTimeout( function() {

                    var txt = td.text();
                                    td.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    console.log(txt);
                    console.log(typeof txt);

                                    //validation then do ajax

                }, 1000);

        });
```